# How to run a function that sits on an add-in in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

Is there any way to run a function that sits an an Excel add-in using VBA? I don't want to hard wire the add-in through the references in VBE. I want to refrence the add-in as a workbook. I could extract the vbproject name, but I cannot run routines using it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it's going to be installed as an add-in, why *wouldn't* you add it as a reference?

Comment: You could try using `Application.Run`

Comment: The add-in is used by many users and it is constantly updated. The index/name of the add-in changes when we update and if we hard wire it, the connection will be lost. Plus, I have written a code to uninstall the older version and install the new version of the add-in automatically. It should be something inside the code so there is no need for a manual operation.

Comment: To use Application.run, the name of the workbook is needed. The add-in should be referenced as an add-in and that is why I am trying to find a way to do that through coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way after Tim suggested to use Application.Run. It is possible to use Application.Run without referencing the full path of the routine. That way it must be made sure that the name of the routine or function called from add-in is unique.